# Using fluentd in docker to get nginx logs

Tags: docker, nginx, kibana, fluentd

I have a scenario where `nginx` is running in one container and `fluentd` is in another container, i mapped `nginx` logs to `var/logs/nginx` directory, but i was unable to retrieve logs to elastic search using `fluentd`, please help me regarding this:

fluentd.conf

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/nginx/access_in_log
  #pos_file /var/log/td-agent/nginx-access.log.pos
  tag nginx.access
  format nginx
</source>


<match nginx.access>
  @type elasticsearch
  logstash_format true
  host elasticsearchkibana
  port 9200
  index_name nginxindex
  type_name nginxlogtype
</match>
```

Please let me know what am I missing.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by using the nginx syslog driver (http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html).

In my `nginx.conf` inside the nginx container I have these settings:

```
http {
...
access_log syslog:server=<FLUENTD_HOST>:<FLUENTD_PORT>,tag=nginx_access;    
error_log syslog:server=<FLUENTD_HOST>:<FLUENTD_PORT>,tag=nginx_error info;
```

In my `fluent.conf` inside my Fluentd container I have this config:

```
<source>
    @type syslog
    port 5141
    tag "syslog"
</source>
```

The logs then look like this:

[image: Nginx access and error logs in EFK]

Comment: Hi, could you please give the docker-compose yaml for your entire application?